# Android application executing code in the background

Tags: java, android, background, multitasking

A very simple question:

I know that Android applications run in the background when they are closed.  Is it possible for my application to keep working while it is in the background?  For example, maintaining a timer in the application to automatically perform a function every hour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use services for doing tasks in background. more info is here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html.

Answer (score 1):

An alarm service should meet your needs; [here's an example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html).

Answer (score 1):

To run things in the background (or outside of the main application thread) there are a few options. To do something very quick in the background the easiest way is to use an AsyncTask. It sounds like you are wanting to implement a bit more than an AsyncTask would handle though. For more longterm tasks that you want to run behind the scenes you probably want a Service.

You can have services that run, do what they are supposed to do and then exit, and you can have ones that keep running. Services have a lot of depth. You could use the AlarmService that is linked above by another user, however another approach would be to just make a simple service and use a TimerTask http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.htm

Remember though, when you are doing things in the Service, they will be being done on the Main Thread, which could slow down other programs, so any logic over long periods of time needs to be accomplished in an AsyncTask.